# Passing data between controllers in MVC Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Express and Node to build an app.

I have a route called '/new-poll' and '/poll-create'

```
//The poll-create route will give the user the option of creating a poll
    app.route('/poll-create')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            res.sendFile(path + '/public/pollcreation.html');
        });



    //This is the route for creating a new poll by authenticated users. Authentication still needs to be added.     
    app.route('/poll-create')
        .post(function(req, res) {
            console.log('inside poll-create post request');
            console.log(req.body);

            serverHandler.newPoll(req, res, db, function(id) {
                console.log('It worked');
                req.session.poll_id = id;
                res.json(id);
            });

        });

    //The above response will redirect to this route, and here is where the poll data will be served up
    app.route('/new-poll')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            console.log('Inside get request for new poll');
            console.log(req.session.poll_id);
            res.sendFile(path + '/public/pollvisualization.html');
        });

    //This is the route for making a post request to the same URL. Specifically to obtain the document inserted previously through creating a new poll
    app.route('/new-poll')
        .post(function(req, res) {
            console.log('Inside new poll post');

            serverHandler.check(db, req.session.poll_id, function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('There is an error');
                    throw err;
                }
                if (doc) {
                    res.json(doc); //send the json document generated by the poll creation by mongoDb to pollvisualizationClient.js through ajax-functions.js
                }
            });

        });
```

Now, I have 2 controllers, controllerData and controllerNonData.

controllerData passes in data to the above POST request using an AJAX call. controllerNonData needs to access the data passed to the POST request by controllerData.

How can I do this in the simplest possible manner? Essentially, my question boils down to what is the easiest way to pass data between view controllers in Express and Node?

The way I'm doing it right now is, I make a POST request with data from controllerData and then make a POST request without data from controllerNonData and then try to differentiate between the two calls in the POST request. But, it seems like a giant pain!

NOTE: I am not using AngularJS in my app. Mentioning this because all the answers I have seen on StackOverflow mention ways to do this in AngularJS.

EDIT: 
Code for controllerData

```
(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (typeof FB !== 'undefined' && FB !== null) { //this if statement is to ensure FB object loads before doing anything else 

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function() {
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

                    var data = {}; //setting up the data object to fill with objects

                    $('.submit-butt').on('click', function() {

                        data.formData = $('form').serializeArray(); //this is the form data from the form
                        data.facebookData = response.authResponse; //facebook object data
                        console.log(data);

                        data = JSON.stringify(data); //this is done to pass the data and parse it through body parser. Not sure why it works this way. 
                        ajaxFunctions.ready(ajaxFunctions.ajaxRequest('POST', appUrl + '/poll-create', data, function() {
                            window.open('https://fcc-votingapp-redixhumayun.c9users.io/new-poll', '_self');
                        }));

                        return false; //setting this statement to false ensures that the form data does not automatically submit independent of the AJAX call 
                    });
                });
            });

        }
        else {
            location.reload(); //reloads the page in case the if statement is not satisfied. 
        }

    });
})();
```

Code for controllerNonData

```
(function() {
    var value; //variable to store the value of the radio option selected
    var custom_flag = false; //flag variable to check whether Custom radio button was selected

    //This is where the AJAX request is initialized
    ajaxFunctions.ready(ajaxFunctions.ajaxRequest('POST', appUrl + '/new-poll', null, function(data) {

        //Parsing the data into JSON format below
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //this is the form data that has been provided via the AJAX request
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);

            var options_count = data[0].options_counter; //this variable stores the options_counter, that is the number of options

            var options_array = getSeperatedOptions(data[0].options);

            var options_length = Object.keys(options_count).length; //finding out the length of the options_counter object in this line

            //updating the header element
            $('h1').html(data[0].title);

            //Invoking the function that will create all of the options required by the user
            createOptions(options_length, options_array);

            //This method here checks to see if the user has selected Custom as their option
            $('.radio-options').on('click', function() {
                var entered_value = getEnteredOption(options_length); //calling this function to check if Custom has been chosen.
                if (entered_value == options_length) { //parseInt of entered_value will return a NaN. Use this to check against the number that is returned for parseInt of the other radio buttons
                    $('.custom-div').show();
                    custom_flag = true; //set the custom flag to true here because Custom radio button was selected
                }
            });

            $('.btn-danger').on('click', function() {
                ajaxFunctions.ready(ajaxFunctions.ajaxRequest('POST', appUrl + '/new-poll/delete-poll', data[0]._id, function(data) {
                    console.log('This is data: '+data); //data contains the number of documents deleted
                }));
            });

            //Submit button event click handler
            $('.submit-butt').on('click', function() {
                //if statement decides whether the radio button selected was the Custom radio button
                if (custom_flag == true) {
                    var entered_value = $('.custom-text').val();
                    value = entered_value; //assigning the local entered_value to a global value variable to use in the next AJAX function
                }

                //else if statement decides whether a radio option button is checked or not! Fires only if Custom not selected
                else if ($('.radio-options').is(':checked')) {
                    var entered_value = getEnteredOption(options_length); //Function call to get option entered by user. Returns the value of the radio button
                    value = entered_value; //assigning the local entered_value to a global value variable to use in the next AJAX function
                }

                //Fire this else statement if no option is selected but Submit button is clicked
                else {
                    window.alert('You need to choose an option before trying to submit');
                }

                if (value.length > 0) {
                    var dataToPass = {}; //defining this object to pass data as JSON
                    dataToPass.value = value;
                    dataToPass = JSON.stringify(dataToPass); //stringify data to pass it through without error

                    ajaxFunctions.ready(ajaxFunctions.ajaxRequest('POST', appUrl + '/new-poll/option-entered', dataToPass, function(data) {

                        //This object contains the returned value from the above AJAX call 
                        data = JSON.parse(data);

                        var optionsArray = getSeperatedOptions(data.value.options); //Keep the difference between optionsArray and options_array in mind AT ALL TIMES!

                        //This function is used to convert the options_counter object to an array so that it can be used to render the chart using ChartJS
                        var options_counterArray = convertOptionsCounterToArray(data.value.options_counter);

                        //call to function to create chart here
                        createChart(optionsArray, options_counterArray);
                    }));
                }
                else {
                    window.alert('Hi!');
                }


            });
        });
    }));

})();
```

EDIT: I have also updated my routes to use sessions.

Comment: can you show how your controllers are defined

Comment: You mean the directory structure or the code defining them?

Comment: code defining them

Comment: Okay, just updated the edits

Comment: @ZaidHumayun Did you have any progress with this?

Comment: @nikjohn - Hey, so I tried implementing the singleton method you told me about, but I didn't understand how I could do it for my case. My view controllers are on the client side and I had access to the data only on the server side. So for the current project I am working I decided to do it using express-sessions. However, I need to find a better way to do this for future projects because what I have done is not very robust. Do you have any resources I can use to understand more about passing data around when using MVC architecture?

Comment: `express-session` can be used to temporarily maintain state, like in the cause of Authentication information. Your question is pretty broad - are you talking about client side MVC or server side MVC? I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: So, the controllers are on the client side, but the data I need access to is on the server side. I needed to pass data from one view controller to the route req object and then I would make a call to the same req object to access the same data from a different view controller. I just wanted a simpler way of doing that versus what I did, which was make one request with no data and another request with data and then try to differentiate the two.

Comment: Hmm I don't completely understand - when you say pass data from one controller to the route req, you mean make an Express API call, right? When you say you wanna make a call to the same **request obj** does that mean the same **route** on Express?

Comment: And when you say you wanna access the same **data** does that mean the data that was passed from your client side controller to express in your previous request?

Comment: @nikjohn - Yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming that your Controllers are on the client side. `http` is a stateless protocol. So in order to pass data between states, you need to implement some kind of caching mechanism. There are a few ways to do this:

- Use HTML5 `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` API *directly*, based on the length of time you want to save the data. Make sure you clear the storage once you're done with the data, to prevent hitting [the 5MB limit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). Using `localStorage` will allow you to use the data till it is manually cleared. `sessionStorage` will live as long as the tab is open.
- Use some other kind of client side storage like Web SQL
- If you want to store data within a page reload cycle (i.e. you will lose data once you reload the page), you can create a Javscript singleton function and inject it into both of your AJAX calls as a dependency, and store your response in that object. This is similar to what happens in AngularJS's Service providers. This is cleaner than the other two approaches, but is of course, shorter lived (unless used on conjunction with one of the above Storage APIs)

#### [Creating singletons in Javascript](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/)

```
var UserStore = (function(){
  var _data = [];

  function add(item){
    _data.push(item);
  }

  function get(id){
    return _data.find((d) => {
        return d.id === id;
    });
  }

  return {
    add: add,
    get: get
  };
}());
```